# How to exclude missing date in Start & EndDate logic?

Tags: sql-server

I want to find Start & End Date here. The input data looks like this. Missing date should not be in Start & End Date.

| RollNo | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1/1/2018 |
| 100 | 1/2/2018 |
| 100 | 1/3/2018 |
| 100 | 1/5/2018 |
| 100 | 1/6/2018 |

The output should be like:

| RollNo | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1/1/2018 | 1/3/2018 |
| 100 | 1/5/2018 | 1/6/2018 |

I tried different solutions and nothing works. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Not everyone here is American, so you should be careful about using ambiguous formats like `m/d/yyyy`. Those could be "first day of the month" values as opposed to consecutive days.

Comment: "Gaps and Islands" is the key phrase you can google to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #IHaveGaps(RollNo int, Date date);

INSERT #IHaveGaps(RollNo, Date) VALUES
(100, '20180101'),
(100, '20180102'),
(100, '20180103'),
-- gap here
(100, '20180105'),
(100, '20180106');
```

We can use `DENSE_RANK()` to identify the "islands" separated by more than a day:

```
SELECT RollNo,
       StartDate  = MIN(Date),
       EndDate    = MAX(Date)
FROM
(
    SELECT RollNo, Date,
       grp = DATEADD(DAY , -1 * DENSE_RANK()
             OVER (PARTITION BY RollNo ORDER BY Date), Date)
    FROM #IHaveGaps
) AS t GROUP BY RollNo, grp;
```

Output:

| RollNo | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-03 |
| 100 | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-06 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=b768dccd9e75c8ce8db39b0c450565d7)

Comment: Thank you: I didn't know this 'trick' of grouping by  `-1 * dense_rank()`. Why do you use `dense_rank()` and not `rank()` It yields the same results

Comment: @Kendle Dealer's choice? I prefer no gaps?

Comment: I see now. If there are duplicate values `Dense_Rank()` will say there are no gaps, `Rank()` will say that there is a problem. The right one to use will depend on the situation?

Comment: @Kendle In this case it doesn't matter, but when it does, I usually prefer `DENSE_RANK()` because I'm usually not looking for the output that `RANK()` provides. It's like `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` - I always use `CONVERT()` because sometimes I need to (there are things it does that `CAST()` does not, but the reverse is not true).